# Easy way to print arabic numbers

Tags: java, for-loop, numbers, arabic

I want to print numbers from 1...10000 with latin and arabic numbers.
is there a fast and easy way to print arabic numbers from 1...10000 in a for loop?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below code to convert  in Arabic.

```
     int arabic_unicode = 1632;
          int num = 786;
            String str_en = num+"";
            StringBuilder builder_ar = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i < str_en.length(); ++i) {
                builder_ar.append((char) ((int) str_en.charAt(i) - 48 + arabic_unicode));
            }

System.out.println("Arabic : " + builder_ar.toString());
```

Above code convert an int to Arabic number. to print 1------10000 you can use a loop accordingly. Please now try yourself.

Comment: With groovy, I only get as output `Arabic : ٧٨٦`

Answer (score -1):

Just a start :

```
$ perl -CS -Mutf8 -le 'print join " ", reverse map { chr oct "0x06F$_" } 0 .. 9' 
۹ ۸ ۷ ۶ ۵ ۴ ۳ ۲ ۱ ۰
```

But you have to read about Unicode UTF8 if you want to go further.

#### EDIT

check [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html#DecimalFormatSymbols%28java.util.Locale%29)

> This class represents the set of symbols (such as the decimal
>   separator, the grouping separator, and so on) needed by DecimalFormat
>   to format numbers. DecimalFormat creates for itself an instance of
>   DecimalFormatSymbols from its locale data. If you need to change any
>   of these symbols, you can get the DecimalFormatSymbols object from
>   your DecimalFormat and modify it.

Comment: @sputnik: sorry I forgot to write that I need it for java code